# Expression is not modfiable

Tags: c++

I have a repository full of dogs and I must update them. 
I have tried updating their age using this:

```
bool Repository::updateDogAge(const Dog& d, const int& ageToUpdate)
{
    {
        Dog* dogsInDynamicVector = this->dogs.getAllElems();
        if (dogsInDynamicVector == NULL)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < this->dogs.getSize(); i++)
        {
            Dog d2 = dogsInDynamicVector[i];
            if (d2.getName() == d.getName())
                d2.getAge() = ageToUpdate;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

but it gives me a compiler error at d2.getAge() that says it is not a modifiable value.
Also I tried changing their name using a similar function:

```
 bool Repository::updateDogName(const Dog& d, const std::string& nameToUpdate)
{
    Dog* dogsInDynamicVector = this->dogs.getAllElems();
    if (dogsInDynamicVector == NULL)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < this->dogs.getSize(); i++)
    {
        Dog& d2 = dogsInDynamicVector[i];
        if (d2.getName() == d.getName())
            d2.getName() = nameToUpdate;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Despite the fact they are almost identical, this one doesn't give me an error, but it just doesn't change the value. 
The getName is defined like this :

```
std::string getName() const { return name; }
```

and getAge:

```
int getAge() const { return age; }
```

Thank you! Sorry for the newbish question.

Comment: `getAge` returns an integer - why do you want to modify a temporary value?

Comment: Ugh then I didn't quite understand the concept, I guess. I'll look into it.

Comment: You probably want to add `setAge` and `setName` functions that actually change the values stored inside the `Dog` object

Comment: Our teacher recommended us to try doing that without setters for some reason . But I'll probably do that, thank you

Comment: And I think you probably want to use the second version that gets a reference to the object stored in the vector, `Dog& d2 = dogsInDynamicVector[i];` to modify the object in the vector rather than a copy of a `Dog` from the vector. I assume that `dogsInDynamicVector` is some kind of a collection class such as a `vector` that you want to update?

Comment: @BryukiHK Functions return by value unless the return type is a reference type. The `int` returned by `getAge()` is a copy of `age;`, not the same `int`. Changing that copy would not have any observable effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the getter/setter pattern wrong. Getter functions's purpose is to read the value, not modify it.
To modify the value, you need to create a setter function for it, like this:

```
void setAge(int a) { age = a; }
```